# Can Node.JS on OpenShift be upgraded?

Tags: openshift

On OpenShift, Node.JS is running 0.10.35 which is over a year old.

Can this be upgraded to 5.x?

cheers
S

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be a way to specify the version of nodejs for your OpenShift cartridge. Here is the official documentation: https://blog.openshift.com/any-version-of-nodejs-you-want-in-the-cloud-openshift-does-it-paas-style/ and also this is a custom Node.js cartridge that takes care of auto-updating the Node.js and NPM versions on each build https://github.com/icflorescu/openshift-cartridge-nodejs.

Comment: cool, it seems like the repo from the 1st link was pulled, and for the 2nd link I would had to re-install my cartridge, which is not a big issue, but I found this to work nice in my existing project: https://github.com/ryanj/nodejs-custom-version-openshift