# How can I run latest version of node on Openshift?

Tags: node.js, openshift, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I have a node app which got a lot of ES6 code and wouldn't run below node version 5.0.0. I have to deploy it on Openshift but its node-cartridge has a very old version of node. Is there a way to deploy my code on Openshift without re-writing it in ES5?

Comment: can you please tell me how you can see which version of node your application is running?  i can't find it in the online console or via searching for openshift cli approaches.

Answer (score 1):

This is the link in OpenShift that allows you to use the latest Node.JS versions. It is available up to 5.11 at this time, as is specified at https://semver.io/node/stable.

https://hub.openshift.com/quickstarts/243-node-js-latest

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to upgrade the version of nodejs there is already a topic on this here [Can Node.JS on OpenShift be upgraded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34757516/can-node-js-on-openshift-be-upgraded/34760041#34760041). We have shared a few custom cartridges that may work in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Try ramr's nodejs-custom-version-openshift repo: https://github.com/ramr/nodejs-custom-version-openshift

It includes some scripts for installing nodejs locally during the build process.